# ¿Como utilizar una variable como valor en una clausula Where In? SQl Server 2016

Tags: sql-server

Eh estado investigando una manera de hacer una consulta con una clausula where in y me he encontrado con el problema de que en la mayoria de los casos es utilizando consultas dinamicas y realmente no tengo idea de como utilizarlas y comprenderlas para usarlas, este es el codigo que quiero utilizar:

```
DECLARE @Val varchar(max)       
set @Val=(select Val from tblUserSetting where ID=7)


select workDayId, EmployeeName, 
case when (JobPosition='Student' or JobPosition='Profesionista en desarrollo' or JobPosition='Prácticante')
then 'Student'
else JobPosition
end as 'Job Position', 
Director,
hireDate
from dbo.TableHeadCount
where workDayId in (@Val)
```

Lo que guarda mi variable @Val es lo siguiente:

> 1163108,10980,913215,10243

Entonces, como podria hacer funcionar esto? mi objetivo es que dentro de mi tabla dbo.TableHeadCount solo busque los registros mencionados dentro de la variable para despues insertar los resultados en una tabla temporal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Y por eso el diseño de tu tabla no es el apropiado. Necesitas usar una función que convierta la cadena en valores individuales. Eso se tendrá que hacer cada vez que se consulte algo, lo cual puede generar más carga en el CPU y memoria. No recomiendo usar código dinámico porque abres la puerta a la inyección de SQL.

Te dejo la función que utilizo yo y que es de las más rápidas en T-SQL antes de que existiera STRING_SPLIT(). La explicación de la función se puede encontrar [aquí (en inglés)](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2).

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD]  
--===== Definir parámetros de entrada
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))  
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS  
 RETURN  
--===== Tabla de números "al vuelo" que genera números del 0 al 10,000...  
     -- suficiente para manejar VARCHAR(8000)  
  WITH E1(N) AS (  
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL   
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL   
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1  
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 filas  
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 filas  
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 filas max  
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== Genera una base cero y limita el número de filas antes de crearlas 
                     -- para obtener mejor rendimiento y prevenir errores
                 SELECT 0 UNION ALL  
                 SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@pString,1))) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4  
                ),  
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== Regresa N+1 (posición inicial de cada "elemento" solo una vez por cada divisor)
                 SELECT t.N+1  
                   FROM cteTally t  
                  WHERE (SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter OR t.N = 0)   
                )  
--===== Dividir la cadena. La combinación ISNULL/NULLIF maneja la longitud del último elemento cuando ya no hay divisores
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.N1),  
        Item = SUBSTRING(@pString,s.N1,ISNULL(NULLIF((LEAD(s.N1,1,1) OVER (ORDER BY s.N1) - 1),0)-s.N1,8000))  
   FROM cteStart s  
;
```

Y la función la usarías así:

```
DECLARE @Val varchar(max);

SELECT  @Val = Val 
FROM    tblUserSetting 
WHERE   ID=7;


SELECT  workDayId, 
        EmployeeName, 
        CASE WHEN JobPosition IN( 'Student', 'Profesionista en desarrollo', 'Prácticante')
            THEN 'Student'
            ELSE JobPosition END AS 'Job Position', 
        Director,
        hireDate
FROM  dbo.TableHeadCount
WHERE workDayId IN (SELECT Item 
                    --FROM STRING_SPLIT(@val, ',') 
                    FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(@val, ','));
```

Dejo ambas opciones con una comentada por si tienes STRING_SPLIT() disponible en tu version de SQL Server.

Comment: Utilice STRING_SPLIT() porque con la funcion no me mostraba todos los registros y con el otro si.  Al final es lo unico que se me ocurrio(Diseño de tabla), puesto que aun sigo aprendiendo y no tengo idea de que opciones más puedo utilizar, igualmente muchas gracias!

Comment: Para saber de un mejor diseño, tienes que estudiar acerca de la normalización de tablas.